# csv.writer writing all strings (in one row) in one cell

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have an automatically generated list in the follwoing text. When I want to save the list to csv, all the values are put in one cell.

```
import csv 

List= '62.000000    56.000000   103.966000  -5.999540'
f=open('dataanalyse1.csv','w',newline ='')
write=csv.writer(f,delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
write.writerow([List])
```

How can I save the values in four seperate cells?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `list` object that you're dealing with but a `str` object.

This should work.

```
import csv


s = '62.000000    56.000000   103.966000  -5.999540'
with open("custom.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    write=csv.writer(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    write.writerow(s.split())
```

The key here is to split the string with respect to spaces but one should remove empty strings.